# How to use ReCaptcha using PHP and Jquery Ajax?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, recaptcha

Since, I'm bit new to php and ajax programming. So, I'm bit confused on how to implement or maybe best practice for security concerns for my website http://www.deerpages.co since this is my first project for myself.

I want to implement ReCaptcha but how?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: http://www.google.com/recaptcha, this is your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Check Recaptcha PHP library. https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/php?hl=it

It's really easy to implement and verify.

Comment: I'll follow this link and implement. thanks for the quick response.